# Alternate between 2 threads

Tags: c, multithreading

I wanted to make a program that writes the odd and even numbers between 1 and 100 with 2 functions , the first function prints the first 5 odd numbers , the second function prints the first 5 even numbers and again we return to the first function to print the second 5 odd numbers and so on .
In this program i wanted to alternate between only `2` threads , but i can't find the solution . Here's my code , in this code i created `40` threads.Does anyone knows how to alternate between 2 threads and find the same output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
pthread_t tid[40];
int pair=2;
int impair=1 ;
pthread_mutex_t lock;

void* genpair(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0 ; i<5 ; i++,pair+=2)
    {
        printf("%d ",pair) ;
    }
printf("  ");    
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return NULL;
}
void* genimpair(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0 ; i<5 ; i++,impair+=2)
    {
         printf("%d ",impair) ;
    }
printf("  ");    
pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j=0 ;
    int err;

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for(j=0 ; j<20 ; j+=2)  
    {
        pthread_create(&(tid[j]), NULL, &genpair, NULL);
        pthread_create(&(tid[j+1]), NULL, &genimpair, NULL);
        pthread_join(tid[j], NULL);
        pthread_join(tid[j+1], NULL);           
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please describe the current behaviour of your program. But for starters, put a `printf("\n")` before the `pthread_mutex_unlock` to flush the buffered output so that it will appear on stdout.

Comment: There is no point using threads for your task.

Comment: @nwp There is if it is a learning exercise. Or if it is an MCVE derived from a larger program.

Comment: Two semaphores, one unit.  That is how it is done.  The unit acts as a 'permission-to-work' token.   The threads swap the unit around on the two semaphores.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You must use 2 different mutex and your code be like this

```
//Thread pair
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&pairLock)
  //Do pair job
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&impairLock)
}

//Threa impair
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&impairLock)
  //Do impair job
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&pairLock)
}
```

The mutex of the starting thread must start at 1 (unlocked) and the other one at 0 (locked)

Edit: Using the same mutex for all your threads makes that only one thread can do it's job but doesn't force any order or alternance (Depends on system scheduler). In your case `genimpair` could execute first if scheduler says so, but it won't be interrupted by `genpair`, in the next loop it could be same order or not

Comment: i still can't see how i can alternate between these 2 functions n times only using 2 threads .

Comment: Start every thread then `lock` and `unlock` the corresponding mutex the number of times you need to print all the numbers you want. Like `for(){ lock(); job(); unlock();}`

Comment: Your solution can't work, because two threads can enter their job at the same time! The first acquire `pairLock` and the second `impairLock`, they are two different locks!

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Of course there are two different locks!!! One starts at 0 and the other at 1, one thread unlocks the other. You should test it at least before downvoting...

Comment: You cannot unlock a mutex that you did not lock.  This solution is dead in the water.

Comment: @Mr.E As Martin mentions, you cannot unlock a mutex you didn't lock. The pthread doc says that this results in undefined behavior (ie your hdd can get reformated). The fact that it may happen to do what you want on the implementation you tested is not enough for this to be a valid answer. It isn't. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html, second paragraph (If a thread attempts to unlock a mutex that it has not locked or a mutex which is unlocked, undefined behavior results.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot ensure which thread will be able to pass before the other with mutexes only. A mutex is there only to ensure that only one thread will be able to run the critical code. You can use a conditional variable associated to your mutex to make them pass one after the other, as in the following pseudo code:

```
// thread1
do {
  lock(m);
  while (turn==0) cond_wait(m); // release the key if not my turn, retry until my turn
  do my job;
  turn = 0;                     // give hand to the other
  cond_broadcast(m);            // awake threads waiting for key (blocked in lock or cond_wait)
  unlock(m);                    // release the lock
} while ();

// thread2
do {
  lock(m);
  while (turn==1) cond_wait(m);
  do my job;
  turn = 1;
  cond_broadcast(m);
  unlock(m);
} while();
```

You can also use two semaphores for the same job...

Comment: Certainy not! cond_wait is a blocking call.